# DevExpress gridView Columns Add

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm using DevExpress library.

I have problem with GridControl the following property is not appear :

```
gridView1.Columns.Add(); // not appear why ?
```

My references are:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns;
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have not added references in solution explorer..

I follow the steps below:

```
GridColumn col=new GridColumn();
col.Caption = "Samples";
col.FieldName = "Samples";
gridView1.Columns.Add (col)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
GridColumn column = gridView1.Columns.AddVisible("FieldName", string.Empty);
gridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the columns visible. 
try the following code:

```
gridView.Columns.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
               gridView1.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn());
gridView1.Columns[i].Visible = true;
}
```